# React custom control return values

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have following state variables

```
const [college,setCollege]=useState({})
```

When a data is fetched from DB, I am using following statement to set the college object

```
function fetchData()   {setCollege(data)}
```

"college" object has array of "students"

I am using a map statement to iterate through the "students" as follows

```
college.students.map((std,i)=>
    {
      <tr> <td>std.name </td>
      </tr>
 }
```

My problem is :
First time (say college "a" has 30 students), everything works great

But when next time, data is fetch for another college say "b" which has 10 students, still the Map function uses old "student" object which has 30 students and the code fails

In actual, when I fetch new college details, inner student object also needs to get updated but its not working during map.

Could you please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create a new object when your data is received, this way it will rerender the component:

```
function fetchData()   {setCollege({...data})}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and answer. Spread operator fixed the issue